# How to style a file upload?

Tags: html, css, firefox, file-upload

In firefox it looks like a text field that you click on and i just need a button like safari renders..Is there a way to not display the text field looking file upload in firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asked many times before:

- [How can I style a file input field in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352467/styling-issues-with-a-file-input-field-in-firefox)
- [Styling an input type="file" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button)
- [How to style "input file" with CSS3 / Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226167/how-to-style-input-file-with-css3-javascript)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984815/jquery-best-way-to-style-a-input-file-tag
- [Can we change <input type="file"> style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825509/can-we-change-input-typefile-style)
- [Style of input=File as a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009300/style-of-inputfile-as-a-button)